# How to achieve a strong attraction of an electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to create an electromagnet that will attract objects from as far away as possible.
I tried almost all options, thin copper with glue, a strong rod, even tried to create a thermal copper pipe.
The magnet itself turned out to be quite powerful, but it does not attract from a distance.

The only thing I have not tried using ferrofluid

I would like the magnet to attract from a very long distance, well, or from the maximum possible.
Tell me what else you can try, maybe I don’t know something.

Comment: *a very long distance* Can you quantify that ?  1mm, 1cm, 1m, 10m, 100m ?  In any case this seems like an engineering question to me.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine At least 5 centimeters would be super with an attraction force of 1 kilogram

Comment: [DIY Super Electromagnet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzXRFp0DDrU)

Comment: @mmesser314 In the video, the magnet is very large, I am now trying to make the magnet as small as possible in size.
At least 4 times less than in the video with the same properties.

Answer (score 1):

About the only way is to make the magnet **big**. Outside the immediate vicinity of the magnet, the field falls at least as fast as $r^{-3}$.